# Airflow : AirflowSkipException doesn't work

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I run a python script through Airflow.
The script gets a source file from S3. I want to set the script to mark the task as 'skipped' when there is no file in the bucket.

```
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowSkipException

if len(file_list) == 0 : #This means there's no file in the bucket. I omitted some codes.
    print('The target file does not exist. Skipping the task...')
    raise AirflowSkipException
```

However, Airflow still marks this task 'failure' when the file doesn't exist.
Am I missing anything? Should I add something to DAG too?

Comment: Raising an `AirflowSkipException` will set the current task + all downstream tasks to skipped (assuming default trigger rules). It must be set to failed for a reason, check the logs to understand why Airflow considers your task to be failed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should call `raise AirflowSkipException()` with the round parentheses at the end, otherwise you are not raising an instance of the AirflowSkipException class, but the class itself which I guess is creating the error that sets the task to failed.